# Accessing List Images

Tags: sharepoint

I'm trying to display the ListItems in a gridview.

I am able to access the list items.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://mysitehere......"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList list = web.Lists["TestList"];
        .......
        .......
    }
}
```

How can I access the list images?

Answer (score 1):

The list images can be access by using code such as the following:

```
 SPListItemCollection listItems = list.Items;

 foreach (SPListItem listItem in listItems)
 {
     SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(listItem.ID);
     string imageUrl = item.Url; //use imageUrl to do whatever ...
 }
```